# Binding a List on POST with AJAX and FormData

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

I'm attempting to bind a list of "Product Specifications" to my "Add Product" dialog. The submit is carried out with AJAX.

Since I allow the user to upload a product image on this same form, I am sending my AJAX request with a 'FormData' object in lieu of serializing.

The result is that the controller action is never reached due to the Specifications list not being in a format expected by the controller.

### ProductModalViewModel

```
public class ProductModalViewModel
{
    public ProductModalViewModel()
    {
        Product = new Product();
        Specs = new List<Spec>();
    }
    public Product Product { get; set; }

    //Other properties removed for brevity

    public List<Spec> Specs { get; set; }
}
```

### View (Modal)

```
<form id="formSaveProduct" onsubmit="SaveProduct(event)" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type="hidden" asp-for="Product.Id" />

//Removed other form fields for brevity

<div class="specs-list-group">
    <ul class="list-group">
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Specs.Count(); i++)
        {
            <li class="list-group-item">
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Specs[i].Id" />
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-5">
                        <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.Specs[i].Name" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-5">
                        <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.Specs[i].Value" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
</div>
</form>
```

### Script

```
function SaveProduct(e) {
        e.preventDefault();  // prevent standard form submission

        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("SaveProduct", "ProductManagement", new { Area = "Admin" })",
            method: "post",
            data: new FormData($('#formSaveProduct')[0]),
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.success) {
                    $("#exampleModal").modal('toggle');
                    location.reload();
                }
                else {
                    $(".modal-body").html(result);
                }
            },
            error: function (e) {
                alert("Error: " + e.status)
            }
        });
    }
```

### Controller

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult SaveProduct(ProductModalViewModel model)
 {
     //Save
 }
```

### Request Header

```
FormData:

Product.Id: 1
Product.Brand: Browning
Product.Model: Gold Mossy Oak Shadow Grass Blades
Product.ProductNum: 723654
Product.CategoryId: 4
Product.IsActive: true
Product.Overview: This is an overview of the tkjsldfgn jlfdgl-sdfgn lkjgfnjkl dfsngkl kjlngkldf jngjkln kdfjnggf h sd sdfgdf...
Specs[0].Id: 1
Specs[0].Name: Test Spec 1
Specs[0].Value: Test Value 1
Specs[1].Id: 2
Specs[1].Name: Test Spec 2
Specs[1].Value: Test Value 2
Specs[2].Id: 3
Specs[2].Name: Test Spec 3
Specs[2].Value: Test Value 3
```

This form works entirely fine until I add in the specifications list. What do I need to change to bind a list while using a FormData object?

---

EDIT: Added Spec Entity for troubleshooting reference.

```
public class Spec
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Spec(string name, string value)
    {
        Name = name;
        Value = value;
    }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Product")]
    [Required]
    public int ProductId {get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }

    //Timestamps
    public DateTime? Created { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Modified { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your `#formSaveProduct`code as well? Also, I think `div.specs-list-group` needs to be inside `#formSaveProduct`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've added more details about the form to the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the model parameter in your Controller's action to use the `[FromForm]` attribute:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveProduct([FromForm]ProductModalViewModel model)
{
    //Save
}
```

You can read more about binding behavior [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.2#customize-model-binding-behavior-with-attributes).

**UPDATE:**

I suspect your issue is coming from two things:

1. Your `Spec` class does not have a parameterless constructor
2. The ProductId is [Required], but you are not passing a product ID in your POST

**Here would be my suggestion:**

You really shouldn't be putting Entity models in your your Views.
I would suggest you create a new class called `SpecDto` and follow these rules

1. Only add properties that you want submitted from the client
2. Have a parameterless constructor.
3. Only use relevant attributes. Do not use entity related attributes like `[ForeignKey("Product")]`

Like this:

```
public class SpecDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public DateTime? Created { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Modified { get; set; }
}
```

And you should do the same for product.

Then your ViewModel should look like:

```
public class ProductModalViewModel
{
    public ProductModalViewModel()
    {
        Product = new ProductDto();
        Specs = new List<SpecDto>();
    }

    public ProductDto Product { get; set; }
    public List<SpecDto> Specs { get; set; }
}
```

In your controller, you then transfer the data from DTO classes to your entity models. I know it seems tedious, but it is the proper way to do such things. If you have a big project, use [AutoMapper](https://automapper.org/) to transfer data. If your project is really small in scope, then *maybe* you could argue a case to use the Entity Models in your Views, but generally it is not a good idea.

Comment: Thank you. I've actually been reading up on [FromForm] today and certainly see why it's needed. I've added it in, however I still receive the same 500 error when the model is being passed to the action (and only when the Spec properties are part of the ViewModel. It works fine when they are omitted.).

Comment: Hmm, can you post the `Spec` class in your question?

Comment: I've added it to the bottom. Thanks.

Comment: @GrahamMeehan see my updated comment. can you let me know if that fixes your issue?

Comment: Thanks for the great suggestions. I tried the first 2 ideas out to no avail, so I'm going ahead and making the DTO classes. I'm happy to take the time to do it right and will report back!

Comment: It works! The lack of DTO was the issue all along. Goes to show how important that layer it. Thanks so much for the help! You've saved my day!